# How to get values from an Array in Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

JS :

```
const data = {
'Test01' : [
    {
        "isActive": false,
        "status": "Clos",
    },
    {
        "isActive": true,
        "status": "Open",
    }
],

'Test02' : [
    {
        "isActive": false,
        "status": "Winning",
    },
    {
        "isActive": true,
        "status": "Closed",
    }
]


export const getCasesByTypology = (typology) => { 
if (typology) return data[typology];
/*if there's no parameters i want to return all values in this example i want to return "isActive": false,
        "status": "Clos", "isActive": true,
        "status": "Open", "isActive": false,
        "status": "Winning", "isActive": true,
        "status": "Closed"*/
var x =  Object.values(data);

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    return x[i];
    //with this loop it returns only the values of  Test01 
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` immediately exits a function. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
return Object.values(data).flat();
```

Which would return:

```
[
  { isActive: false, status: 'Clos' },
  { isActive: true, status: 'Open' },
  { isActive: false, status: 'Winning' },
  { isActive: true, status: 'Closed' }
]
```

Where `flat()` flattens an Array of Arrays into a single Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for in for loop

```
 array1.forEach(i=>{
        i.forEach(j=>{
           console.log(j);
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function that exists for this in javascript.
Example -

```
let arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]; // arr = [Array(3), Array(3)]
let temp = arr.flat(); // temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```